# SHDocVw Convert to Selenium get all innertext of tagname

Tags: vb.net, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I need to convert this into selenium I'm using VB.net and MS Edge

```
        Dim findDupli As IHTMLElementCollection = HTML.getElementsByTagName("td")

        For Each element As IHTMLElement In findDupli

            If element.getAttribute("classname") = "maskable" Then
            End if

        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Selenium to get html elements via tag name, you can try this method ( using python):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME , 'td')
```

For more details, you can refer to this doc: [Locating Elements by Tag Name](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-tag-name).